# Get with preg_match_all anchor text inside a div with specific class

Tags: php, html

I have the following div:

```
<div class="myclass"><strong><a rel="nofollow noopener" href="some link">dynamic content</a></strong></div>
```

and I want to get only the:  `dynamic content` anchor text.

so far I have tried with `preg_match_all`:

```
"'<div class=\"myclass\">(.*?)</div>'si"
```

that returns all div content.

I tried to combine it with:

```
"|<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|i"
```

that returns anchor text but I cannot make it to work

can someone help?

thank you

Comment: I think you should read this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags before you fall down into the "html and regex"-rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DOMDocument` instead to `preg_match_all`

```
$html = '<div class="myclass"><strong><a rel="nofollow noopener" href="some link">dynamic content</a></strong></div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = './/div[@class="myclass"]/strong/a';
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

echo $nodes[0]->textContent;
```